# SGE job getting killed

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I am trying to run a job on SGE, but it keeps being killed. I'm not sure which parameter I should change in my script.

My submit.sh script:

===========

```
#$ -l mem_free=32G
#$ -l h_rt=48:00:00

## softx will require 8 processors
softx myprogram.sh
```

==========

and I submit it to SGE:

```
qsub -q long.q submit.sh
```

What should I change?

The details of the killed job and the queue defaults are below

```
qacct -j 740
```

==============================================================

```
qname        long.q
hostname     node02.local
department   defaultdepartment
jobname      submit.sh
jobnumber    740
taskid       undefined
account      sge
priority     0

granted_pe   NONE
slots        1
failed       37  : qmaster enforced h_rt, h_cpu, or h_vmem limit
exit_status  137                  (Killed)
ru_wallclock 1588s
ru_utime     0.110s
ru_stime     0.190s
ru_maxrss    5.520KB
ru_ixrss     0.000B
ru_ismrss    0.000B
ru_idrss     0.000B
ru_isrss     0.000B
ru_minflt    25267
ru_majflt    0
ru_nswap     0
ru_inblock   0
ru_oublock   176
ru_msgsnd    0
ru_msgrcv    0
ru_nsignals  0
ru_nvcsw     351
ru_nivcsw    95
cpu          10096.930s
mem          429.730GBs
io           76.911GB
iow          0.000s
maxvmem      8.635GB
arid         undefined
ar_sub_time  undefined
ar_sub_time  undefined

category     -q long.q -l h_rt=172800,mem_free=32G
```

=====

```
qconf -sq long.q

qname                 long.q
s_rt                  864000
h_rt                  864000
s_cpu                 INFINITY
h_cpu                 INFINITY
s_fsize               INFINITY
h_fsize               INFINITY
s_data                INFINITY
h_data                INFINITY
s_rss                 INFINITY
h_rss                 INFINITY
s_vmem                INFINITY
h_vmem                8g
```

Comment: Have you tried submitting the job without specifying h_rt?

Answer (score 1):

The queue has an h_vmem limit of 8g which is enforced on jobs regardless of what they request.  Since the job is killed after half an hour it shouldn't be the h_rt limit that is the problem.   The job reports a max_vmem in excess of the queue limit.  You need to talk to the cluster administrator about how to submit such jobs or alter the problem so it uses less virtual memory.